# How to get from the TraceBackFrame to the ScriptSource

Tags: debugging, ironpython, traceback

I'm currently experimenting with lightweight debugging via Python.SetTrace(). But I cannot find a generic way from the callback parameters (TraceBackFrame stackFrame, string stEvent, object payload) to the ScriptSource containing the code.

I can map for the ScriptSource on which I initially called Execute(), by matching the file path (either ScriptSource.Path equals TraceBackFrame.f_code.co_filename, or the latter one is "string" when no file is involved).

But my search for any references pointing from the TraceBackFrame to the ScriptSource (which works for other python files executed by the script via import, exec, execfile etc.) was without success.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this - can you describe what you're trying to accomplish?  If you're creating the script sources you could look at stackframe.f_code.co_filename and maintain a mapping of filenames to ScriptSources you create.  But that would only work w/ ScriptSources you make and that have filenames.

Comment: The customer want a "trace" functionality, similar to "echo on" on DOS batch files. So for every executed line, they want to have the source printed out. And for modules the script executed itself (via import, exec, execfile etc.), I don't create the ScriptSource. Is there any Hook / Callback I can link into the IronPython runtime? (I think an own PlatformAdaptionLayer is to low-level for this...) Maybe the only workaround is to use co_filename and read the file myself...

Comment: I just opened a wishlist issue on http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/30103 - we'll see what happens. Maybe I even find enough time to hack that myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record: Our current solution is now to parse the source files on our own, if a file is available. For the stackframes not backed by a file (e. G. eval), we simply cannot trace them.